# jquery special character as seelector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a simple `hover` to work on a special char as a selector.

I'm using the `double-daggers` ( ‡ `&#8225;`) special char

ASCII 8225 and want to make these function as a tool tip but i'm having trouble actually getting them to fire the event.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/briansol/xdS7V/) with a click action instead of hover for simplicity:

What am I missing? I feel like this should be simple.

Maybe it's just the end of the work day.

Comment: you can't select text with CSS, therefore you can't do it with a jQuery selector either. text nodes also can't have click or hover events.

Comment: Make life easy on yourself, and wrap the text in a div, and select the div.  Then it doesn't matter what the text is.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein or a `span` since I'm assuming it's inline text

Comment: Incidentally, on the fiddle, you hadn't set it to use jQuery, and once that is set, if you had the console open when running, you would've seen an error on the select statement you had: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &#8225"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [jQueryUI tooltip widget](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)?

It allows you to set any element to have a tooltip, simply by specifying a `title="Text for the tooltip goes here"` attribute.

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $( document ).tooltip();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Using your daggar<span title="This is a tooltip">&#8225;</span> symbol.</p>
        <p><a href="#" title="That's what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover
        the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>

        <p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
        <a href="http://themeroller.com" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI's theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a>
        will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>

        <p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>

        <p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>

        <p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this is the best solution, as i am using UI already.
Thanks to all who answered.  I tried to give you all some points for the time.

Answer (score 4):

You can't make a selector that finds a character, because a selector can only find elements.

Wrap the character in an element that you can target. Example:

```
<span id="asdf">&#8225;</span>
```

Then you can find the element:

```
$("#asdf").click(function() { alert('hovered'); });
```

Comment: he will not want to use an id as he will want to use this multiple times per page if it is a tooltip...

Comment: @DrCord: Maybe, maybe not. If there are multiple tooltips there might be different information in them...

Comment: There would almost certainly be different info in them but he would want to write a function that pulls the tooltip in dynamically and bind the click to all the tooltips on the page, not separately for every single tooltip on the site...

Comment: In either case whether he uses an id or a class or even an attribute it's irrelevant. the solution is that it's wrapped in an element.

Answer (score 1):

$("‡") is not a legal jQuery selector. Try wrapping it in a span with a class and then selecting that.

```
<span class="tooltip">&#8225;</span>

$(".tooltip").click(function() { alert('clicked'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors target DOM elements. You can't select just text with them, and therefore you can't get to it with jQuery. You need to wrap it in a `<span>` tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/xdS7V/3/

HTML:

```
<span class="tooltip">&#8225;</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".tooltip").click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As all the other answers about putting it in a span, but you can select it by purely the content...

```
$("span").filter(function() {
    return this.innerText == "‡";
}).on("mouseover", function() { alert('hovered'); });
```

**[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdS7V/4/)**